# on every step use iteration of ngFor as per index

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have an array of object and I am running `ngFor` on that. I want to show different view for each iteration of `ngFor`.

```
const HEROES = [
    {id: 1, name:'Superman'},
    {id: 2, name:'Batman'},
    {id: 5, name:'BatGirl'},
    {id: 3, name:'Robin'},
    {id: 4, name:'Flash'}
];
```

Like `Superman` should be default view then when I click next `Batman` should be shown, the next will be `BatGirl` and so on.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Add an object to your component to keep track of the selected hero. Then, update this hero on click accordingly (if I understood your question correctly).

Comment: i need to to show one complete object in heros at a time and on every click it should iterate to next object

Answer (score -1):

You can one variable holding the currently selected object.

in html

`

```
<div>
    <span>{{selectedObj.name}}</span>
</div>
```

`

In ts file intially, you can have

selectedObj = { };

count = 0;

this.selectedObj = HEROS[count];

on each time you click on next button

next()

{

```
this.count ++;

this.selectedObj = HEROS[count];
```

}